# Maps on android drop a pin

Tags: android, google-maps, user-experience

I need to show google map to user and then resolve the address on that map.
I wonder what's the recommended approach for best user experience in Android?

The ways I was thinking of is:

1. Show current location (or default if not permitted). Put a pin at the place where user taps on the map. If tapped again, then just move the pin. Resolve the address where last pin was dropped
2. Another approach is same to what uber has: show the map with a pin in the center of the viewport pointing to current location. That pin is still in the center and consumes new position when map is moved against it. Address is resolved when map movement stop event received

Disadvantages of #1 is that it might be not obvious for user that pin needs to be placed on the map

Is there a best practice for this? Or a more intuitive way to do this?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

These tasks need Google Cloud Api And That is paid.
Reference Links:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/overview

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com?project=my-application-359006